# Open Request Permissions in Android Even if Permission is already granted

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

I am working on android application in which i am  requesting permissions.
It works fine for the first time, but when i try to disable the permission, the requestPermission dialog does not appear. i want the dialog to appear even if i uncheck the switch button. The case should be following:
i enable switch: should open request permission.
i disable switch: should open request permission.

[image]

```
   aSwitchWifi.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Permissions.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
            else {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Permissions.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you always want to request permissions why not get rid of the logical steps and just call 'ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Permissions.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);' every time?

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how permissions work. If user already granted a permission (or denied it twice) you won't be able to show dialog for it anymore. At this point you can only inform the user that they has to open app settings and alter it manually there. Also revoking permissions is unhandled in normal application flow so when you do it system kills the app process to prevent issues.